# Dijkstra's algorithm in c++ infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I was trying to implement Dijkstras's algorithm in c++. Now i have trouble debugging. Somewhere in my code there is an infinite loop. And my graph implementation sucks. if you have any ideas what is wrong with my code even if it is not about the main problem tell me.

I don't need somebody elses code i need it to be my code but fixed so i can find my mistakes in code and better understand it (i only understand my codes sadly c++ compiler doesn't).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

vector < vector<int> > graf;
int fromnode, tonode;

struct nodeinfo
{
    //this contains info about a node
    bool visited = 0;
    int dis = INT_MAX/2;
};
nodeinfo sample;
vector<nodeinfo> info; // if visited
queue<int> togo;

// dijkstra algorithm
void dijkstra(int currnode)
{
    //visited current node
    info[currnode].visited = 1;
    //go see every node connected to the current one
    for(int i = 0; i < graf[currnode].size(); i ++){
        if (graf[currnode][i] != INT_MAX/2 ) {
            // if visited push to queue and check distance
            if(info[i].visited== 0)
                togo.push(i);
            info[i].dis = max(info[i].dis,info[currnode].dis + graf[currnode][i]);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    //input n
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    //declaring variables
    graf.resize(n*2);
    info.resize(n*2);
    vector<int> fillin (100,INT_MAX/2);
    graf.insert(graf.begin(),100,fillin);
    int a,b,c;

    //input in graphinfo[graf[currnode][i
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        if (graf[a][b] > c)
            graf[a][b] = graf[b][a] = c;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    // input from witch node to go and where to go and
    cin >> fromnode >> tonode;
    info[fromnode].dis = 0;
    togo.push(fromnode);
    //dijkstra start
    while(!togo.empty()){
        dijkstra(togo.front());
    }
    // output
    cout << info[tonode].dis << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

after i had put   `cout << "at node " << currnode << endl;` at the beginning of dijskstra function using this input:

[image]

It was stuck on node 1:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop says

```
while(!togo.empty())
```

but you never remove anything from `togo`.
You'll want to `pop` at a suitable place.
(Finding a suitable place left as an exercise.)

Comment: oh. wtf how did i miss that? thanks man. and btw  i just realised that my code was looking for a max instead of min path thanks it works

Comment: got some ideas for fixing my graph implementation? I would really appreciate that. I mean so i could use more than 100 nodes : graf.insert(graf.begin(),100,fillin);

Comment: and other sh** i typed out for no freaking reason